# Open Source Finance Modules in PHP

Tags: php

I am searching for Open Source Finance scripts such as Account Payable, Account Receivable, General Ledger etc in PHP. But I couldn't find a good one.

Is there any such open source scripts in PHP available over the web for download?

If so, could you please give me the links.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a [list of open source accounting software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_accounting_software) help? The "Further details" section shows there is a few written in PHP.